# Open source convert .idb .mdb database

Tags: gdal, ogr, esri-geodatabase, open-source-gis, linux

Is there a way to convert a geodatabase (ArcGIS Geodatabase Version 9 according to their website) to other formats such as shapefiles / geopackage for feature layers and geotiff for rasters using a open source solution?

I am trying to convert:
http://www.cger.nies.go.jp/db/gdbd/data/Africa.zip

from website:
http://www.cger.nies.go.jp/db/gdbd/gdbd_index_e.html

I tried GDAL (2.1.1,) and OGR but the driver is not supported. Export using Arcmap works fine but I prefer a linux based solution that can easily be automated.

Database contents in ArcMap and ArcCatalog below

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is an ArcGIS v9? In v9, there was only a personal geodatabase (`.mdb` file of Microsoft Access database). The only thing I recall that had something to do with `idb` is that there were rasters that were stored inside an image database (`IDB`) folder. The `IDB` folder were located in the directory next to the personal geodatabase. So it's best if you could verify the data type of your input data before trying to convert it :)

Comment: Added some details about the database to the questions. Mixed type (raster, polygon, line)

Comment: See the [OGR Personal GeoDatabase](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html) docs. No raster support though. You could use arcgis arcpy on Linux to automate if you can set up an ArcGIS Server instance.